# Detectar datos de HTML en método de una clase

Tags: javascript

Estoy intentando hacer un generador de RFC, que consisten en la primer letra del apellido paterno, la primer vocal de apellido paterno, la primer letra del apellido materno, la primer letra del nombre, los últimos dos digitos del año de nacimiento, el mes y el día.

Al ejecutar el siguiente código, me da el error **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'charAt' of undefined at HTMLButtonElement.calculoRfc**

Si creo un nuevo elemento con datos ya establecidos, si me corre el código, no me lo genera si quiero agarrar los datos del HTML

```js
var pnombre = document.getElementById('nombre')
var papellidoPaterno = document.getElementById('apellidoPaterno')
var papellidoMaterno = document.getElementById('apellidoMaterno')
var pdiaNacimiento = document.getElementById('diaNacimiento')
var pmesNacimiento = document.getElementById('mesNacimiento')
var panoNacimiento = document.getElementById('anoNacimiento')
var button = document.getElementById('button')
var texto = document.getElementById('texto')
console.log(pnombre)
class persona{
    constructor(nombre, apellidoPaterno, apellidoMaterno, diaNacimiento, mesNacimiento, anoNacimiento){
        this.nombre = nombre,
        this.apellidoPaterno = apellidoPaterno,
        this.apellidoMaterno = apellidoMaterno,
        this.diaNacimiento = diaNacimiento,
        this.mesNacimiento = mesNacimiento,
        this.anoNacimiento = anoNacimiento
    }
    calculoRfc(){
        console.log("hola")
        var letra1 = (this.apellidoPaterno).charAt(0);
        for(var i=0; i<(this.apellidoPaterno).length;i++){
            if(((this.apellidoPaterno).charAt(i)=='A')||((this.apellidoPaterno).charAt(i)=='E')||((this.apellidoPaterno).charAt(i)=='I')||((this.apellidoPaterno).charAt(i)=='O')||((this.apellidoPaterno).charAt(i)=='U')){
                var letra2 = (this.apellidoPaterno).charAt(i);
                i=(this.apellidoPaterno).length;
            }
        }
        texto.innerHTML = (`${letra1}${letra2}${(this.apellidoMaterno).charAt(0)}${(this.nombre).charAt(0)}${(this.anoNacimiento).slice(2,4)}${this.mesNacimiento}${this.diaNacimiento}`)
        console.log(`${letra1}${letra2}${(this.apellidoMaterno).charAt(0)}${(this.nombre).charAt(0)}${(this.anoNacimiento).slice(2,4)}${this.mesNacimiento}${this.diaNacimiento}`)
    }
}
var datos = new persona(pnombre,papellidoPaterno,papellidoMaterno,pdiaNacimiento,pmesNacimiento,panoNacimiento)
button.addEventListener('click', datos.calculoRfc);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Generador RFC</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Calcular tu RFC sin homoclave</h1>
        <input type="text" id="nombre" placeholder="Nombre">
        <input type="text" id="apellidoPaterno" placeholder="Apellido Paterno" >
        <input type="text" id="apellidoMaterno" placeholder="Apellido Materno" >
        <p class="subtitulo">FORMATO (dd)</p>
        <input type="text" id="diaNacimiento" placeholder="Día de nacimiento" >
        <p class="subtitulo">FORMATO (mm)</p>
        <input type="text" id="mesNacimiento" placeholder="Mes de nacimiento" >
        <p class="subtitulo">FORMATO (aaaa)</p>
        <input type="text" id="anoNacimiento" placeholder="Año de nacimiento" >
        <button id="button">Calcular</button>
        <p id="texto"></p>
    <script src="rfc.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema es que los nombre de variable contienen una referencia al elemento de cada caja de texto y no al valor en si. Por este motivo no se puede aplicar un `charAt` directo, si no antes de obtener su valor con la propiedad `value`.

Otro problema es con el **`this`**, Tener presente que el contexto (this) de una funcion es el objecto que lo invoca (en tu caso this es el boton). Te dejo un enlace para que lo leas ([this en javascript](http://www.etnassoft.com/2012/01/12/el-valor-de-this-en-javascript-como-manejarlo-correctamente/)).

Y por ultimo la variable `letra2` la utilizas fueras del bloque donde la declaras y tbn te faltaron varios punto y comas.

Te dejo el codigo corregido, al cual solo le agrege la propiedad value y los puntos y comas.

```js
var pnombre = document.getElementById('nombre');
var papellidoPaterno = document.getElementById('apellidoPaterno');
var papellidoMaterno = document.getElementById('apellidoMaterno');
var pdiaNacimiento = document.getElementById('diaNacimiento');
var pmesNacimiento = document.getElementById('mesNacimiento');
var panoNacimiento = document.getElementById('anoNacimiento');
var button = document.getElementById('button');
var texto = document.getElementById('texto');

class persona{
    constructor(nombre, apellidoPaterno, apellidoMaterno, diaNacimiento, mesNacimiento, anoNacimiento){
        this.nombre = nombre,
        this.apellidoPaterno = apellidoPaterno,
        this.apellidoMaterno = apellidoMaterno,
        this.diaNacimiento = diaNacimiento,
        this.mesNacimiento = mesNacimiento,
        this.anoNacimiento = anoNacimiento;
    }
    calculoRfc(){
        var letra1 = apellidoPaterno.value.charAt(0);
  var letra2 = "";
        for(var i=0; i<apellidoPaterno.value.length;i++){
            if((apellidoPaterno.value.charAt(i)=='A')||(apellidoPaterno.value.charAt(i)=='E')||(apellidoPaterno.value.charAt(i)=='I')||(apellidoPaterno.value.charAt(i)=='O')||(apellidoPaterno.value.charAt(i)=='U')){
                letra2 = apellidoPaterno.value.charAt(i);
                i=apellidoPaterno.value.length;
            }
        }
        texto.innerHTML = (`${letra1}${letra2}${apellidoMaterno.value.charAt(0)}${nombre.value.charAt(0)}${anoNacimiento.value.slice(2,4)}${mesNacimiento.value}${diaNacimiento.value}`);
    }
}
var datos = new persona(pnombre,papellidoPaterno,papellidoMaterno,pdiaNacimiento,pmesNacimiento,panoNacimiento);
button.addEventListener('click', datos.calculoRfc);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Generador RFC</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Calcular tu RFC sin homoclave</h1>
        <input type="text" id="nombre" placeholder="Nombre">
        <input type="text" id="apellidoPaterno" placeholder="Apellido Paterno" >
        <input type="text" id="apellidoMaterno" placeholder="Apellido Materno" >
        <p class="subtitulo">FORMATO (dd)</p>
        <input type="text" id="diaNacimiento" placeholder="Día de nacimiento" >
        <p class="subtitulo">FORMATO (mm)</p>
        <input type="text" id="mesNacimiento" placeholder="Mes de nacimiento" >
        <p class="subtitulo">FORMATO (aaaa)</p>
        <input type="text" id="anoNacimiento" placeholder="Año de nacimiento" >
        <button id="button">Calcular</button>
        <p id="texto"></p>
    <script src="rfc.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

errores:

1. solo seleccionas los input pero no tomas su valor
2. eres de python? debes aprender que javascript utiliza `;` al final
   de las lineas
3. tu if solo compara letras mayusculas

> **nota:** tambien coloque las variables dentro del `addEventListener` ya que
>       apenas inicializa el documento aun no tienen valor, debes esperar al
>       click del button para recojer su valor

```js
class persona{
constructor(nombre, apellidoPaterno, apellidoMaterno, diaNacimiento, mesNacimiento, anoNacimiento){
    this.nombre = nombre;
    this.apellidoPaterno = apellidoPaterno.toUpperCase();
    this.apellidoMaterno = apellidoMaterno;
    this.diaNacimiento = diaNacimiento;
    this.mesNacimiento = mesNacimiento;
    this.anoNacimiento = anoNacimiento;
}

calculoRfc(){
    let letra1,letra2;
    console.log(this.apellidoPaterno);
    letra1 = this.apellidoPaterno.charAt(0);
    for(let i=0; i<(this.apellidoPaterno).length;i++){
        if(((this.apellidoPaterno).charAt(i)=='A')||((this.apellidoPaterno).charAt(i)=='E')||((this.apellidoPaterno).charAt(i)=='I')||((this.apellidoPaterno).charAt(i)=='O')||((this.apellidoPaterno).charAt(i)=='U')){
            letra2 = this.apellidoPaterno.charAt(i);
            console.log(this.apellidoPaterno);
            i=(this.apellidoPaterno).length;
        }
    }
    texto.innerHTML = (`${letra1}${letra2}${(this.apellidoMaterno).charAt(0)}${(this.nombre).charAt(0)}${(this.anoNacimiento).slice(2,4)}${this.mesNacimiento}${this.diaNacimiento}`)
    console.log(`${letra1}${letra2}${(this.apellidoMaterno).charAt(0)}${(this.nombre).charAt(0)}${(this.anoNacimiento).slice(2,4)}${this.mesNacimiento}${this.diaNacimiento}`)
}
}

button.addEventListener('click',function(){
  let pnombre = document.getElementById('nombre').value;
  let papellidoPaterno = document.getElementById('apellidoPaterno').value;
  let papellidoMaterno = document.getElementById('apellidoMaterno').value;
  let pdiaNacimiento = document.getElementById('diaNacimiento').value;
  let pmesNacimiento = document.getElementById('mesNacimiento').value;
  let panoNacimiento = document.getElementById('anoNacimiento').value;
  let button = document.getElementById('button');
  let texto = document.getElementById('texto');
  let datos = new persona(pnombre,papellidoPaterno,papellidoMaterno,pdiaNacimiento,pmesNacimiento,panoNacimiento);
  datos.calculoRfc();
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Generador RFC</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Calcular tu RFC sin homoclave</h1>
        <input type="text" id="nombre" placeholder="Nombre">
        <input type="text" id="apellidoPaterno" placeholder="Apellido Paterno" >
        <input type="text" id="apellidoMaterno" placeholder="Apellido Materno" >
        <p class="subtitulo">FORMATO (dd)</p>
        <input type="text" id="diaNacimiento" placeholder="Día de nacimiento" >
        <p class="subtitulo">FORMATO (mm)</p>
        <input type="text" id="mesNacimiento" placeholder="Mes de nacimiento" >
        <p class="subtitulo">FORMATO (aaaa)</p>
        <input type="text" id="anoNacimiento" placeholder="Año de nacimiento" >
        <button id="button">Calcular</button>
        <p id="texto"></p>
    <script src="rfc.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```